# Facebook taggable_friends returns json picture URL, but URL is invalid

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I get a json back from Facebook when using taggable_friends:

{"id":"aaifpxqtnzaoxzj1htqpj3mx4xbjlipvuvch9muqueia1ic2xr3iqv1ouyisuk9ob8xknuwb1rk5poy92stj6oho1aiowst6lcx6dsz32pzibw",
"name":"jan pietersen","picture":{"data":{"is_silhouette":false,
"url":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/c22.22.276.276/s50x50/1002729_391175754325150_673656636_n.jpg?oh=
0f95c73655a7d1ba4d0a9b7418cb00a0&oe=5593eb6a&**gda**=1431088369_3978aa4d6e53a85856463087f4b37e93"}}}

I get the picture URL from this string that looks like this:

[https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/c22.22.276.276/s50x50/1002729_391175754325150_673656636_n.jpg?oh=0f95c73655a7d1ba4d0a9b7418cb00a0&oe=5593eb6a&**gda**=1431088369_3978aa4d6e53a85856463087f4b37e93](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/c22.22.276.276/s50x50/1002729_391175754325150_673656636_n.jpg?oh=0f95c73655a7d1ba4d0a9b7418cb00a0&oe=5593eb6a&__gda__=1431088369_3978aa4d6e53a85856463087f4b37e93)

That doesn't work because when checking on Facebook it should look like this:
[https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/c22.22.276.276/s160x160/1002729_391175754325150_673656636_n.jpg?oh=0203e560f071eb42dcf6bdec99a74e1b&oe=55583D9F&**gda**=1432062559_2c1d594d9b7c6ff542e47d169d3b670f](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/c22.22.276.276/s160x160/1002729_391175754325150_673656636_n.jpg?oh=0203e560f071eb42dcf6bdec99a74e1b&oe=55583D9F&__gda__=1432062559_2c1d594d9b7c6ff542e47d169d3b670f)

Anybody a clue what I am doing wrong?

Andy.

Comment: When did you get the url back? You are aware that it is a temporary url that will stop work after a while. If you do a call now to taggable_friends does it still return the wrong url?

Comment: Same problem... I removed the app and tried again... I do get an ID, Name of the person and picture with URL. I first tought I cannot copy the link because then the senders page isn't the GET page so maybe Facebook does a check on this. Even when building the picture in the page itselve (where I have the GET) doesn't do the trick...

Comment: If the url you get back is not loading file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #50.d61645f.1423676809.7f4d1c0d